# Other words for "help"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, sentence

I want to express the meaning of:

> Something comes as a help (or support) to another thing.

Could we say...?

> Comes to back up the other thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could, though there's a risk of misinterpretation. "Back up" has several other specific meanings - particularly in relation to computer data and road traffic.

It's not wrong, but something like "assist" or "aid", or the older-sounding "avail" or "succour" (spelling dependent on location) might work better.

[Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/help) has some good alternatives, though it's thrown the nouns and verbs into the same pot. The question also refers to both, so the [something] being discussed "comes to assist" or "comes as an assistance".

The suggestion from the question of "support" is good, too, and avoids the confusion of "back up" (though it might add confusion from sports fans or financial contributors).